# Adding exported jpeg files to Lightroom again - how to preserve exact keywords?

Tags: lightroom, metadata, keywords

I got a lot of RAW files I want to keep as jpeg files. So I export them from Lightroom (*use same folder like original file*, *add to this catalogue*, include *all metadata*).

My image has the single keyword *cat* in a keyword hierarchy like

> animal > mammal > cat

The exported jpeg file however, which was added to the LR library, has the whole keyword hierarchy as individual keywords.

How can I automatically retain the original keyword only?

Comment: Just to clarify: You checked the metadata _outside_ of Lightroom and are seeing the whole keyword hierarchy?

Comment: @feetwet No, inside Lightroom.

Answer (score 2):

You can edit individual keyword tags in Lightroom, and set them to 'Include on Export' (the default) or not. In your case, if you edit 'animal' and 'mammal' by right-clicking the keywords and choosing 'Edit keyword tag' you can uncheck this option and it will no longer export. See the screenshot below for an example. [image]

Comment: Nick, thanks for your answer. I tried selecting several keywords at once to edit they options. It does not work. So I assume I have to edit every single keyword manually?

Comment: As far as I can tell, you have to edit keywords individually.

Comment: I posted another question: http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/62188/is-it-possible-to-change-the-options-of-multiple-lightroom-keywords-at-once